# SSH specify key while ignoring the default keys

Tags: ssh

I have my SSH client config defined as follows:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
ForwardAgent yes
AddressFamily inet
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yubikey-01-res
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yubikey-05-res
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I need default connections to traverse the yubikeys first and if unavailable- use the ed25519 key.

For github.com I need to specifically use the ed25519 key, but it always defaults to the yubikeys whenever they are plugged in. I would assume that the keys specified per host have precedence over the root keys. Is this expected behavior?

```
~/.ssh ❯ ssh git@github.com -v
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 25: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.248.137.48] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-01-res type 12
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-01-res-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-05-res type 12
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-05-res-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-30fa67d5
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-30fa67d5
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:58
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 4 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-01-res ED25519-SK SHA256:he6uVl0OF/kFNLgxJxBWp1LqFKqUeqGE7QBvXrMV32Y explicit authenticator agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-05-res ED25519-SK SHA256:Ris+zCkAuyo5TNMtSPPw95i50+qfrDpnctJX1VdXb04 explicit authenticator agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4dewvZr3d9r9hEfDz1JyCpe4SedcFT32Purq88AyMhI explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-01-res ED25519-SK SHA256:he6uVl0OF/kFNLgxJxBWp1LqFKqUeqGE7QBvXrMV32Y explicit authenticator agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-01-res ED25519-SK SHA256:he6uVl0OF/kFNLgxJxBWp1LqFKqUeqGE7QBvXrMV32Y explicit authenticator agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-05-res ED25519-SK SHA256:Ris+zCkAuyo5TNMtSPPw95i50+qfrDpnctJX1VdXb04 explicit authenticator agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/yubikey-05-res ED25519-SK SHA256:Ris+zCkAuyo5TNMtSPPw95i50+qfrDpnctJX1VdXb04 explicit authenticator agent
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "/home/user/.ssh/yubikey-05-res" from agent: agent refused operation
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4dewvZr3d9r9hEfDz1JyCpe4SedcFT32Purq88AyMhI explicit agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4dewvZr3d9r9hEfDz1JyCpe4SedcFT32Purq88AyMhI explicit agent
Authenticated to github.com ([20.248.137.48]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the default keys "globally"; list them *after* the Github-specific key following a `Host *` directive.

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
ForwardAgent yes
AddressFamily inet


Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yubikey-01-res
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yubikey-05-res
```

(`Host` directives remain in effect until the next `Host` or `Match` directive. There's no real difference between things listed "globally" at the top of the file before any `Host` or `Match` directive, and things after a `Host *`; you just need `Host *` to "terminated" the preceding `Host github.com` directive. Indentation is just for readability, not scoping.)

Comment: This didn't work, but after taking your suggestion and adding `Host * !github.com` it seems to work now. Thank you